# How to delete records using pipeline trigger schedule time in pre copy script in Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need help to delete records from my destination table before loading into it using azure copy activity in Azure data Factory. My condition is delete the records from snowflake table where snowflaketable.date column is equal to date of pipeline trigger time.

I tried writing below in Pre-Copy script

delete from  "CONSOLIDATE"."SEM"."HEATMAP" where cast(createdate as date ) = cast(@pipeline.triggetime.scheduletime as date)

Can you please help me with correct syntax.

Comment: What is the error message that you see

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using incorrect variables

> There is no variable as `@pipeline.triggetime.scheduletime`

`pipeline().TriggerTime` is the actual time when this pipeline was triggered and not the trigger scheduled time!

**Example:** `2022-01-17T05:44:31.7534445Z`

If you would want to use scheduled time, which I don't think so from you words, you would actually have to use this `@trigger().scheduledTime` variable instead.

Refer: [Schedule trigger scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables#schedule-trigger-scope)

### Example:

First, get current trigger time into a variable

```
@substring(pipeline().TriggerTime,0,10)
```

[image]

And the query in **Pre-copy script** would look like:

```
declare @myvariable nvarchar(max) = @{variables('m')}
delete from POCtest where cast(ExecutedDate AS Date)  = cast(@myvariable as date)
```

[image]

**Result**

[image]

[image]

You can refer to [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) for more specific conversion according to you table schema and datatypes used.